# How to design multiple page sub report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am developing asp.net application. In the report section. I need to generate a details report of the site.

First page would explain the detail of the site. The image, information and etc.

The second page and the following would explain about the aircond on the site. If the site got 5 aircond. then 5 page about aircond would be generate.

But i dont know how to do that on asp.net 2010 crystal report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by using the sub report. the crystal report would automatically generate one sub report of each row. if we got 5 row of aircond. 5 sub report of aircond would be produce..